# Document converter for Android

Tags: gratis, android, document-converter

I'm looking for a free document converter for android that will allow me to convert a .doc(x) (as well as other formats) to a .pdf from another app using android's "share" function. I don't want to have to browse for the file I wish to convert

Features I am looking for:

- Ability to convert the following formats to .pdf:

  - .doc(x)
  - .rtf
  - . xml(x)
  - . txt
- Must be able to convert using the share function from other apps. For example, I am editing a file in app X and I want to send it over to a friend, I would press the "share" button in the app and select app Y to easily convert the file without having to browse for it
- No ads would be a plus, but not required
- No watermarks or other makings on the exported .pdf
- If possible, have offline capabilities (as in the app doesn't have to connect to the web to convert the file, or the app doesn't point me to a website to convert the file)
- Must be free

I have tried WordToPDF and Doc converter but they required me to find the file in my tablet. The big feature I am looking for here is the share function.

Comment: Unfortunately, almost all Android PDF converters for such complex formats are nothing but front-ends to some web service. To pick from a desc: *converting is accomplished by uploading your file to the cloud where it will be converted and downloaded back to your phone*. So you must be aware there are privacy considerations to be taken (same would apply to ads, as adware has the potential to "steal data" as well: the ad module has access to everything the app has access to, including Internet). That OK with you?

Comment: @Izzy Yes that's fine.

Comment: I have not tried any of those myself, hence I cannot give a clear recommendation. Some candidates you might wish to take a look at can be found in [this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=27#group_114); there's e.g. [Ultimate PDF Converter](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.muthusuba.updfconv) working via the share menu, and supporting a range of document formats.